# error to executing try and catch method in twitter application in android

Tags: android, twitter, access-token

Hello I am new on Android and I tried to make twitter integration app. and I got error in  method which is mention below. I want to know why this method does not execute and what can i do to execute this method please help me. Thanx in advance.

My method is

```
  public void authorized() {
    try {
        AccessToken accesstoken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
        Log.d("Authorize Token","" + accesstoken);
        oAuthHelper.storeAccessToken(accesstoken);          
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.d("Error in authorized", "error");
    }
}
```

when app is run only execute catch but i want to execute try Please suggest me.

Comment: What does logcat says?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this - [TwitterOAuthView](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView)

Comment: thanks for giving me reply. I just want to execute try part in authorized() method not execute catch part. When i run it execute catch part. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dude `catch` part is executing because `try` part is throwing `TwitterException`.So I will suggest you to go for `TwitterOauthView` it gives you `onSuccess` & `onFailure` callbacks.